# FreeBSD bass/treble adjustment

Tags: freebsd, audio

I am trying to lower a bit the bass and increasing a bit the trebles when listening sound through external lineout.

```
%cat /dev/sndstat
%sysctl hw.snd.default_unit=0

Installed devices:
pcm0: <Conexant CX20642 (Analog 4ch/2.0)> (play/rec) default
pcm1: <Conexant CX20642 (Analog)> (play/rec)
pcm2: <Intel Cougar Point (HDMI/DP 8ch)> (play)
pcm3: <Intel Cougar Point (HDMI/DP 8ch)> (play)
pcm4: <Intel Cougar Point (HDMI/DP 8ch)> (play)
No devices installed from userspace.
hw.snd.default_unit: 0 -> 0
```

I have tried:

```
% mixer treble 90
mixer: unknown device: treble
usage: mixer [-f device] [-s | -S] [dev [+|-][voll[:[+|-]volr]] ...
       mixer [-f device] [-s | -S] recsrc ...
       mixer [-f device] [-s | -S] {^|+|-|=}rec rdev ...
 devices: vol, pcm, speaker, mic, rec
 rec devices: mic
```

and

```
% mixer treble 90:90
mixer: unknown device: treble
usage: mixer [-f device] [-s | -S] [dev [+|-][voll[:[+|-]volr]] ...
       mixer [-f device] [-s | -S] recsrc ...
       mixer [-f device] [-s | -S] {^|+|-|=}rec rdev ...
 devices: vol, pcm, speaker, mic, rec
 rec devices: mic
```

Note: this works:

```
% mixer 80
Setting the mixer vol from 86:86 to 80:80.
```

FreeBSD 12.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably not available to you. See [mixer(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?mixer(8)) which says:

> Not all mixer devices are available.
>
> Without any arguments, mixer displays the current settings    for all sup-
>   ported devices, followed by information about the current recording input
>   devices.  If the dev argument is specified, mixer displays    only the value
>   for that dev.

So just enter `mixer` to see what is actually available to you. It is actually listed in your error messages:

```
devices: vol, pcm, speaker, mic, rec
```

Only the above are exposed from your soundcard. `mixer 80` works because the device `vol` is available.

All is not however not lost. We can EQ any [pcm](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pcm&sektion=4) stream using "Parametric Software Equalizer".

> EQ is disabled by default, but can be enabled with the `hint.pcm.%d.eq` tunable.

See [3) Parametric Software Equalizer](https://people.freebsd.org/~ariff/SOUND_4.TXT.html) and [Sound Equalizer Help Request](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/solved-sound-equalizer-help-request.44743/)

Comment: Typing `mixer` as stated effectively shows that `bass` and `trebble` are not available.